# 3 way login in different session

Tags: php, mysqli

I use this code but it keeps getting the session of admin when I login as employer I know my conditional statement is wrong what should I do?

```
if ($username&&$password)
            {
                $query = mysqli_query($link,"select * from login where UserId = '$username'");
                $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
                if ($numrows!==0) 
                {
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
                    {
                        $dbusername = $row['UserId'];
                        $dbpassword = $row['Password'];
                        $dbprivileges = $row['Privileges'];
                    }
                    if($username==$dbusername&&$password==$dbpassword)
                    {
                        //admin home page
                        if($dbprivileges=="Admin")
                        {
                            @$_SESSION['admin'] = $username;
                            header('Location:hris_admin_index.php');
                        }
                        //company home page
                        elseif($dbprivileges=="Company")
                        {
                            @$_SESSION['employer'] = $username;
                            header('Location:hris_company_index.php');
                        }
                        //employee home page
                        else
                        {
                            @$_SESSION['employee'] = $username;
                            header('Location:hris_employee_index.php');
                        }
```

Comment: You must learn how to debug. Try putting **echo $dbprivileges;exit;** after the while loop.

Comment: can you post everything even the db code

Comment: What's with the error suppression? Also, you should be [hashing your passwords](http://php.net/password_hash), not storing them in plain text and if you're using mysqli using prepared statements is the most secure, or at least you should be using mysqli_real_escape_string to make sure your code is not vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: im using mysqli_real_escape_string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this but also remember to add `session_start()` :

```
                   if ($username && $password)
                   {
                   $query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM login");
                   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
                    {
                    $dbusername = $row['UserId'];
                    $dbpassword = $row['Password'];
                    $dbprivileges = $row['Privileges'];

                    if($username == $dbusername && $password == $dbpassword)
                    {
                    //admin home page
                    if($dbprivileges == "Admin")
                    {
                        @$_SESSION['admin'] = $username;
                        header('Location:hris_admin_index.php');
                    }
                    //company home page
                    elseif($dbprivileges == "Company")
                    {
                        @$_SESSION['employer'] = $username;
                        header('Location:hris_company_index.php');
                    }
                    //employee home page
                    elseif($dbprivileges == "Employee")
                    {
                        @$_SESSION['employee'] = $username;
                        header('Location:hris_employee_index.php');
                    }
                     }
```

Comment: im adding session start at top